# How do I change an :after css selector based on the scroll position in wordpress?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, wordpress

This is what I have been trying:

This is the default css used when scrolling:

```
.nav-menu .current_page_item > a:after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    width: 0;
    border: 10px solid rgba(35, 31, 32, 0.79);
    border-color: rgba(35, 31, 32, 0.79) transparent transparent transparent;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -10px;
}
```

...and this is the javascript im using:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(window).scroll(function(){ 

    var a = 50px;
    var pos = $(window).scrollTop();
        if(pos < a) { $(".nav-menu .current_page_item > a:after").css({ border: 10px solid #000; border-color: #000; }); }
    });
</script>
```

Could someone tell me where I am going wrong?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: You can't manipulate `:after` using JavaScript. Instead, create a new class with different `:after` properties and add or remove that class using jQuery.

Comment: `:after` is not element in the DOM and so it not selectable in that fashion.